# SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend() works in @Controller class but nowhere else

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I am injecting the `SimpMessagingTemplate` into some of my `@Component` classes in my Springboot app, but `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(dest, payload)` only sends from the `@Controller` class where the websocket endpoints are handled.

Controller

```java
@MessageMapping("/gpio_ws")
    @SendTo("/topic/gpio")
    public GPIOMessage sendGPIOMessage(GPIOMessage message) {
        log.info("Sending WS message: " + message);
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/gpio", message);
    }
```

I have some Javascript in the frontend with Stomp and SockJS which connects and sends messages through this endpoint without a problem.

Example use in another class

```java
// constructor injected, it won't allow field injection here
private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;

@Autowired
public PiGPIO(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
}


// in a method
Arrays.stream(piFace.getInputPins())
                    .forEach(inputPin -> inputPin.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent 
                                                                         event) {
                            log.info("PiFace input had an event - PIN: " + event.getPin().getName()
                                    + " STATE: " + event.getState().getName());
                            template.convertAndSend("/topic/gpio", new 
                                                   GPIOMessage(event.getPin().getName(),
                                    event.getState().getName().equals("LOW INPUT") ? 1 : 0));
                        }
                    }));
```

I did have this working the other day and I'm now at a complete loss.
I checked the bean by clicking the little icon in IntelliJ and all instances of `SimpMessagingTemplate` seem to be pointing to the same bean.

Can `SimpMessagingTemplate` work outside the class where the endpoint is declared? Why not?

Edit:
Here is the websocket config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gpio_ws");
        registry.addEndpoint("/gpio_ws").withSockJS();

        registry.addEndpoint("/track"); // for another SockJS, which works
        registry.addEndpoint("/track").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

A snippet of the Javascript. During putting together the websocket code, I used JS to receive *and* send, but for this particular problem I just need it to receive. Although I have left the send/receive functionality at the moment so I can test the WS is still working.

```js
function connect() {
    const sock_track = new SockJS('/track');
    stomp_track = Stomp.over(sock_track);
    stomp_track.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('stomp_track connected: ' + frame)
    })

    const sock_gpio = new SockJS('/gpio_ws');
    stomp_gpio = Stomp.over(sock_gpio);
    stomp_gpio.connect({}, function(frame) {
        console.log('stomp_gpio connected: ' + frame);
        stomp_gpio.subscribe('/topic/gpio', function(messageOutput) {
            parseMessage(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
            console.log(messageOutput.body)
        });
    });
}

function sendMessage() {
    const pin = document.getElementById('pin').value;
    const state = document.getElementById('state').value;
    console.log("state: " + state + " pin: " + pin)
    stomp_gpio.send("/app/gpio_ws", {},
        JSON.stringify({'pin':pin, 'state':state}));
}

function trackOn() {
    stomp_track.send("/app/track", {}, true)
}

function trackOff() {
    stomp_track.send("/app/track", {}, false)
}
```

Edit:
The class where `SimpMessagingTemplate` `template.convertAndSend()` previously worked, before I had to refactor as I had a circular dependency (I injected PiGPIO here, and GPIOService into PiGPIO).
So previously, GPIOService was injected to PiGPIO and within PiGPIO the method `sendEvent()` was called and this successfully sent a message to the JS client.

```java
@Service
public class GPIOService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GPIOService.class);
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;
    private final PiGPIO piGPIO;

    @Autowired
    public GPIOService(SimpMessagingTemplate template, PiGPIO piGPIO) {
        this.template = template;
        this.piGPIO = piGPIO;
    }

    /** Sends a message to the websocket on /gpio endpoint.
     * @param message is a model of the PIN state, 1 being high, 0 low */
    public void sendEvent(GPIOMessage message) {
        log.info("GPIOMessage sent to /topic/gpio");
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/gpio", message);
    }

    public void trackPower(boolean isPowered) {
        if (isPowered) {
            piGPIO.turnOnTrack();
        } else {
            piGPIO.turnOffTrack();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
Added `@PostConstruct` to two classes where I am trying to use `SimpMessagingTemplate`.

```
@PostConstruct
void onMade() {
    log.info("Bean initialised");
}
```

Starting the app, result seems to show both classes are being found and initialised by Spring?

```
2020-11-16 10:34:16.153  INFO 22346 --- [           main] io.github.siaust.slotcar.service.PiGPIO  : Bean initialised
2020-11-16 10:34:16.168  INFO 22346 --- [           main] i.g.siaust.slotcar.service.GPIOService   : Bean initialised
```

`SimpleMessageBrokerHandler` seems to have zero destinations, I'm not sure if this is a problem or as the app runs this changes.

```
2020-11-16 10:34:24.448  INFO 22346 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [DefaultSubscriptionRegistry[cache[0 destination(s)], registry[0 sessions]]]]
```

Edit:
I added some more log calls to see what is happening with `SimpMessagingTemplate` in the class after it's initialised.

```
log.info(template.getDefaultDestination());
log.info(template.getUserDestinationPrefix());
log.info(template.getMessageChannel().toString());
```

Result

```
2020-11-16 11:37:17.522  INFO 23925 --- [           main] io.github.siaust.slotcar.service.PiGPIO  : null
2020-11-16 11:37:17.523  INFO 23925 --- [           main] io.github.siaust.slotcar.service.PiGPIO  : /user/
2020-11-16 11:37:17.524  INFO 23925 --- [           main] io.github.siaust.slotcar.service.PiGPIO  : ExecutorSubscribableChannel[brokerChannel]
```

I'm just guessing here, but the default destination should not be `null`? Have I got a configuration problem, or should I set the default destination?

Comment: Can this be the issue of session assignment that ended up omitted? I mean messaging template requires ws session to do operations and I see no `@SubscribeMapping` or similar thing in second example.

Comment: Please see my edit for additional info. 
Should I annotate the method I'm using `SimpMessagingTemplate` instance to `convertAndSend()` with `@SubscribeMapping` and subscribe to the endpoint I require?

Comment: No, you're not tied to @SubscribeMapping at all but I suppose that problem resides somewhere else. Having fresh look on your code taken I should wonder why did you have your code structured the way that controller invokes service and not vice versa? If there's no reason for it then the most convenient way is to accept this behaviour and to refactor code to working boilerplate

Comment: My main reason, is that the service class cannot know when to send a message as the listeners are created in the other class. It's poor design by me clearly and I was in the middle of figuring it out. I will probably have to revert to how it was, working, if I can, and figure how to have the listeners notify an event in the service class, maybe with an observer pattern, I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe you can also employ some `@EventListener` + [event publishers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisher.html) to make this work properly. I can attach working configuration if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are doing with the missing config etc.
Not sure what you mean by "checking the bean" bit either.

Here is my set up for a basic "notification" channel.

1. Client hits the STOMP endpoint `/swns/start` to open the STOMP connection.
2. The `/swns/start` endpoint adds the user's principal name and STOMP session ID to a in memmory store.
3. Client `stompClient.subscribe()` to `/notification/item` which is a STOMP broker topic.
4. I can then send message to that user or all users using the class I made below.

The config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class STOMPConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications").setAllowedOrigins("*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/notification");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/swns");
    }
}
```

The Controller

```
@Controller
@Log4j2
public class SocksController {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private NotificationDispatcher notificationDispatcher;

    //Send STOMP message to /swns/start to begin a STOMP WSbased connection.
    @MessageMapping("/start")
    public void send(StompHeaderAccessor stompHeaderAccessor) {

        //Can get Spring Principal/Session user from the STOMP header (awesome!).
        final Principal user = stompHeaderAccessor.getUser();
        log.info("{} initiated a STOMP based websocket.", user != null ? user.getName() : "ANON");
        //Add the user's principal name as the key and their STOMP session Id to the static vol HashMap<String,String> in
        //the NotificationDispatcher.
        NotificationDispatcher.getPrincipalNameToSockSessionMap().put(user.getName(), stompHeaderAccessor.getSessionId());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void onMade() {
        log.info("////////////////////// GIMME UR SOX //////////////////////////////");
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@EnableScheduling
@Log4j2
public class NotificationDispatcher {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private volatile static HashMap<String, String> principalNameToSockSessionMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;


    public void sendToUser(String principalName,String destination,Notification notification) throws NotificationException {

        if(!principalNameToSockSessionMap.containsKey(principalName)){
            throw new NotificationException(String.format("Can not get session for principal name `%s` as there is no session in RAM map.",principalName));
        }
        String sessionId = principalNameToSockSessionMap.get(principalName);

        log.info("Sending targeted notification to {} - {}", principalName, sessionId);
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
        headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
        headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                sessionId,
                destination!=null?destination:"/notification/item",
                notification,
                headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
    }


    @EventListener
    public void sessionDissconectHandler(SessionDisconnectEvent sessionDisconnectEvent) {
        String sessionId = sessionDisconnectEvent.getSessionId();
        log.info("Disconnecting : {}", sessionId);
        principalNameToSockSessionMap.remove(sessionId);
        log.info("Current Sessions Count : {}", principalNameToSockSessionMap.size());
    }

    @Data
    public static class Notification {

        private final String value;

        public Notification(String s) {
            this.value = s;
        }
    }

    public static class NotificationException extends Exception{

        public NotificationException(String s) {
            super(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code (is in React and using Redux)

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: notificationSlice
})

var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost/api/notifications');

  const stompClient = Stomp.over(sock);

      console.log('open');  
      stompClient.connect({}, function () {
        console.log(`STOMP connected : ${stompClient.connected}`)
        stompClient.send("/swns/start", {});
      stompClient.subscribe('/user/notification/item', function(menuItem){
          console.log("MESSAGE!")
          console.log(menuItem)
          store.dispatch(setMessage(menuItem.body))

      });
        console.info('connected!')
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.error(error)
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm trying to find some idea from your code.
I've edited my main post to include the `WebSocketConfig` and JavaScipt. 

I was checking the Spring Bean because I believe, in my limited understanding, that in this case it is not initialising or, it is on the wrong "channel", so to speak. 
When it was working,I injected a class into `PiGPIO` class, which had a method `sendMessage` invoking `SimpMessagingTemplate`'s `convertAndSend`.
Since then I had to refactor, but I'm guessing `SimpMessagingTemplate` was initialised correctly in that particular class, for some reason?

Comment: `// constructor injected, it won't allow field injection here
private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;`
Does indicate that the class is not being picked up by the Applcation bean context manager (forgot its name).
Has it been correctly annotated with `@Component` and the `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` annotations?

Comment: The class where `SimpMessagingTemplate` was working was annotated with `@Service`, which I have tried adding to the class it's currently called from but no effect. The current class is annotated `@Component`. 
I had to refactor as I had a circular dependency problem going on, otherwise I would have left it as it was. I will edit in the class where the `convertAndSend` call worked.

Comment: With `SimpMessagingTemplate`, it is already a defined bean with the websocket dependency added and therefore unless you need to change it for some reason then it should be able to be `@Autowired` in to any context aware class (I.e. `@Component/Sevice/Configuration`).

I'd add in an @PostConstruct on your beans to see if they are starting up?
Like on mine:
```@PostConstruct
    void onMade() {
        log.info("////////////////////// GIMME UR SOX //////////////////////////////");
    }
```

Comment: Edited my post. Seems like both classes are being initialized.
I did notice something in the logs with the `SimpleBrokerMessageHandler` where it seems to have 0 destinations. I added the log message to my post.

Comment: I have a feeling it may be here:
```this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/gpio", message);``` where for STOMP you should be including the headers etc. See https://www.codesandnotes.be/2020/03/31/websocket-based-notification-system-using-spring/